# Bright frames when rendering in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

When rendering a .png sequence in EEVEE 2.80 Beta[image], I'm getting random bright/flash frames (see attached image). When I render still frames, this isn't an issue. None of the lighting changes through the scene, and it seems to affect different frames each time. Sometimes, many will be affected, other times very few or none. I tried rendering an .avi or .mp4, but EEVEE doesn't seem to support those yet, as the program crashes after several frames and the resulting file is corrupt.

I don't know if this is a bug, inherent weakness, or if I'm doing something wrong. Cycles renders the same frames normally.

Comment: I am seeing similar anomalies. In the latest case, I have a bright green flash appear at a random location in a random frame.